# how to get default network connection name used via C#?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I need get it independent if the network connection is active or not.
I need get only dial up connection.

in this picture **Claro** is default netowork connection name.

[image]

Have no idea how do this. I hope this is clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by the 'default' network connection? I'm pretty sure in Windows all of the network interfaces are treated equal.

Comment: @M.Babcock: check out my updated, I add an image

Comment: Must be a dial-up thing. Regardless, if there is actually a property on the network interface to specify it as default, I'd bet it would be accessible through WMI or the raw registry settings.

Comment: I believe there a default network connection for that, for example: connect it automatically when the window OS is start. About WMI query, I think a bit confuse for do this.  I want no use it again,after a lot of work I get the network connection names(as in print above) using ras library. registry settings is a good tip, I'II try it. Thanks once again. ;)

Comment: @M.Babcock:hmm..I believe the USB modem have this information, it is possible get it by using COM,maybe?

Comment: Any chance you can just disable the dial up modems that you don't want to use? If you do, then `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkAdapters` won't return any that aren't enabled so you could guess which one is correct.

Comment: Sorry.. I'm not a native speaker of English,then if you find any mistakes in what I've written,feel free to correct or edit for me.

Comment: Without a similar environment to play with, I'd be hard pressed to make any serious suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the currently selected default connection for connecting to the internet, which [can be set in a couple of ways](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753219%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), you need to read the registry key HKCU\RemoteAccess InternetProfile. This will contain the name of the adapter.

Now the fun part: you will need to use [DotRas](http://dotras.codeplex.com/).

Once you have this downloaded, installed, and reference in your project, you can use code similar to the following:

```
// Get the default adapter
string defaultAdapter = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\RemoteAccess", "InternetProfile", "") as string;

foreach (RasConnection connection in RasConnection.GetActiveConnections())
{
    if (connection.EntryName.Equals(defaultAdapter, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        if (connection.GetConnectionStatus().ConnectionState == RasConnectionState.Connected)
        {
             // Do something
        }
    }
    // Done searching
    break;
}
```

Comment: the problem it is that does not works if network connection is not active.

Comment: @Jack: You could look through all of the adapters and if none are up, look at one or more of the other statuses. You probably also want to exclude adapters with a NetworkInterfaceType of Tunnel or Loopback.

Comment: and if I try to use DotRsa library?

Comment: Did you set the default connection through IE or in the network control panel?

Comment: it's is defined automatically when the connection is installed. But the user can change any time.

Comment: Ok, found a solution. The network interface info does not include RAS info, but there is a project on codeplex for this. Updated the answer with details.

Comment: Great answer! The key name `InternetProfile` is variable? in my computer the key name is `Profile`.

Comment: I'II accept your answer. Thanks very much for your attention and sorry for inconvenience. Just one thing I changed in this code:`var connectionName = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"RemoteAccess\Profile", false).
GetSubKeyNames().First();` it does not get the real default network name, just the first network connection created by the device(a usb modem) that's valid.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you where looking for?

```
  using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {

                Console.WriteLine(nic.NetworkInterfaceType);
                Console.WriteLine(nic.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

if you find out what string it puts for NetworkInterfaceType with modems then you can put a if statement in there

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was answered before, the problem it's that works only for active connections.